# Bluehost primary domain not showing in directory

Tags: hosting, web-hosting, bluehost

Just recently created a Bluehost account with the basic 1 website plan. It Makes the domain I used on sign up the "Primary Domain". I've already changed the name servers on my google domain dashboard. When I go to the file manager and then the "public_html" folder to try and upload my own index.html file to my website folder I do not see my website. I only see WordPress files/folders. When I navigate to my website it says WordPress site coming soon.

How do I upload my own website files to Bluehost so that they are linked to my primary domain?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question. Rather, it is about using Bluehost.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the answer. I had to add the line `DirectoryIndex Index.html home.htm index.htm index.html default.htm` to the `.htaccess` file so that the site points to my `index.html` file placed within the `public_html` folder instead of the WordPress home file.